# MSBuild fails to build a Windows CE project correctly while devenv does

Tags: c#, msbuild, compact-framework, windows-ce

I inherited a bunch of build scripts and reworked them. One of the things I changed was to let MSBuild handle solution files rather then let the Visual Studio devenv.exe build them. Part of the assemblies we have are Compact Framework 3.5 projects targeting Windows CE. The latest Visual Studio version supporting that stuff is VS2008.

I managed to have MSBuild 3.5 build the solutions that were previously built using Visual Studio 2008's devenv.exe. And they seemingly build just fine. Until I deploy them to the Windows CE device and run them. Then I get exceptions that seem to make no sense whatsoever: MissingMethodException or TypeLoadException. All references are there and up to date. It took me a while to figure out MSBuild was the problem. Using devenv.exe again makes the problem go away.

I figured solution files are MSBuild files and all the information needed to properly build a solution file is in that solution file and the project files it references. Yet VS2008 does it better.

What is happening? Why can I not use MSBuild? Or can I? Where is MSBuild screwing up?